# two-dimensional wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a question about "the two-dimensional wave equation", I have solved it but I wanted to know if I've done right. Because the solution is long, I just write the answer but I can write the solution also if you need it.
Thanks in advance

Solve two-dimensional wave equation
$$\frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2}=4*(\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}+\frac{∂^2u}{∂y^2})$$
in $$0<x<3$$$$0<y<2$$

then we have boundary conditions
$$\frac{∂u}{∂x}(0,y,t)=0 $$$$\frac{∂u}{∂x}(2,y,t)=0$$$$\frac{∂u}{∂y}(x,0,t)=0$$$$u(x,2,t)=0$$
and we have and the initial conditions
$$u(x,y,0)=0$$$$\frac{∂u}{∂t}(x,y,0)=g(x,y)$$

My answer is:
$$u(x,y,t)=\sum\sum A_ncos(\frac{pi}{3(1+n)x})*A_mcos(\frac{pi}{2(m+1/2)y})*A_(nm)cos(2 \sqrt{λ})t B_(nm)sin(2 \sqrt{λ})t)$$
but we have $$A_(nm)=0$$
so
$$u(x,y,t)=\sum\sum A_ncos(\frac{pi}{3(1+n)x})*A_mcos(\frac{pi}{2(m+1/2)y})*[B_(nm)sin(2sqrt λ)t)$$
and $$b_(nm)=\frac{<f,Z_(nm)>}{<Z_(nm),Z_(nm)>}=$$
$$=\frac{\int_0^3\int_0^2g(x,y)cos(\frac{pi}{3(1+n)x})*cos(\frac{pi}{2(m+1/2)y})dydx}{2\sqrt{λ_{nm}}\int_0^3\int_0^2cos^2(\frac{pi}{3(1+n)x})cos^2(\frac{pi}{2(m+1/2)y})dydx}$$

Comment: Please use \frac{}{} to do your fractions, where the numerator goes in the first pair of braces. Also, for inner product use \langle and \rangle. I'm finding it quite difficult to go through your work written the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have not used exchnge so much because I'm a little uncomfortable.

Comment: Also the subscript given by "_" only applies to the next single character, if you wish to have multiple you need to enclose them in curly-braces, e.g. $A_ijk$ vs. $A_{ijk}$.

Comment: One thing to do is to plug your proposed answer back into the original equation and boundary conditions and see if they work.  At first glance, I don't see anything obviously wrong with your answer, but it is so easy to make a simple typo in these kinds of problems.